# Kernel Density Estimate in R for Vector of Dates

Tags: r, date, kernel-density

I have a vector of 195 date fields which I'm assigning to variable `xvar` as follows:

```
xvar <-as.Date(getvars[,3],"%m/%d/%Y")
```

I want to be able to fit a distribution over the resulting histogram and subsequently sample from that probability distribution. I can plot the histogram and density of this date vector using `ggplot2` but I'm not aware of a way to sample from the resulting density.

I downloaded the R package `ks`. It works wonderfully well for a vector of real numbers but when I pass it the date vector, after running these lines:

```
xvar <-as.Date(getvars[,3],"%m/%d/%Y") # Vector of Dates
xvnonull <- (na.omit(xvar)) #Remove any NAs
fhat <- kde(xvnonull) #Try to Fit KDE
```

I get an error stating:

```
"Error in rep(1, n) : invalid 'times' argument".
```

I have removed all `NA` values.

Do you have any suggestions on how to go about this problem? Are there alternate libraries/packages out there that will work with dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would plot this (no bells & whistles):

## Data

```
set.seed(1234)
xvar<-
  sample(seq(from=as.Date("2015-01-01"),length.out=100L,by="day")
  )[colSums(matrix(sample(34L,300L,T),nrow=3))-2L]
```

## Solution

```
library(ks)
xvar_f<-as.factor(xvar)
xvar_i<-as.integer(xvar_f)
par(mar=c(5.6,4.1,4.1,2.1))
plot(kde(xvar_i),xaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="",
     main="Density of Dates",las=1)
tx=seq(min(xvar_i),max(xvar_i),by=5)
lb=levels(xvar_f)[tx]
axis(side=1,at=tx,labels=lb,las=2)
```

## Output

[image]